# Подключение базы данных C#

Tags: c#

Всем привет, создал приложение для авторизации пользователя по БД, но при запуске приложения на другом устройстве, не выходит БД, сейчас строка подключения выглядит так

```
string connectString = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Ivan.DESKTOP-2CO6P3I\source\repos\AuthForm\AuthForm\Database1.mdf;Integrated Security=True";
```

пытался заменить адрес расположения на пользовательский ввод, который вводился в переменную конфига:`string connectString = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename="+@Properties.Settings.Default.address+@";Integrated Security=True";`
address вводился в окне при неудачной попытке подсоединения или первом запуске программы, однако не выходило изменить данные в этой бд, хоть и получилось авторизоваться по ее данным
скорее всего, проблема в том, что БД изначально находится в обозревателе решений, возможно ли организовать все это как-то по-другому, без изначального прикрепления бд к проекту, c подключением по адресу, введенному пользователем, либо с возможностью менять значения?

Comment: Не выходит БД - это как? Просто ничего не происходит, exception, приложение не запускается? Какое приложение? Какое устройство?
Можно использовать не localdb, а полноценную базу на mssqlserver. Тогда Вам понадобится продумать доступ к серверу, где бд развернута.

Comment: Добрый день, уже исправил, оказалось, выходило исключение, т.к. не было установлено MSSQLLocalDB на тестовом устройстве(надо было проверить работает ли это на другом устройстве и, если нет, решить проблему)